# how can I create cumulative matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a question please.

I have a matrix `G`with size `(500,500)`. I want to create cumulative matrix of `G`. I know that I can write something:

```
c=reshape(G,1,[])
c1=cumsum(c);
```

in next step I have to convert c1 to the other matrix for example `c2` with size `(500,500)`that is now cumulative of matrix `G`. But I want to create matrix `c2`without reshaping matrix `G`. in fact I want to create cumulative matrix of `G` directly.

is there any way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: Why can you not just create `G` as an intermediate step? Also, rather essential to the question is what is actually in `G`?

Comment: I have many matrices with this specification. creating intermediate step decrease speed of calculation. I have forgotten to say that after creating c1 I have to convert it to other matrix with size "(500,500)" like "G".

Comment: So you're asking how to make a completely unspecified matrix into a cumulative version of itself... providing no information :/

Comment: imagine that G is random matrix like:  `G=randi([0 255],[500 500])`.

Comment: If speed is really your issue then please post the completely code of the bottle neck. Otherwise this question is really meaningless I'm afraid. I'm voting to close as unclear.

Comment: I sent example of my matrices to you in previous comment and also I said that I have many matrices like G. thank you any way.

Comment: Your "example" is that they are random :/

Comment: How should the cumulative matrix be constructed? It matters whether you want to add the value top to bottom, left to right, or the other way around... Also it would be really helpful if you could provide us with the rest of your code. On my (rather old) machine, `cumsum` and `reshape` don't take THAT long to run, so it would be nice to know what you are trying to do with these matrices - perhaps there are 'smarter' speedups to be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to accumulate down each column and then proceeding to the next column, you can use

```
G = rand(5,5); %// example data
G(:) = cumsum(G(:));
```

Comment: Thank you Luis, It's exactly what I want, Thank you very much. also Thank you Wouter for your special tips and your kindness.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the comment I posted earlier, you can achieve about a 20% speedup (at least for my machine it's about 20%) by making the following change:

(original code)

```
G=randi([0 255],[500 500]);
c=reshape(G,1,[]);
c1=cumsum(c);
c2 = reshape(c1,[500 500]);
```

(now without storing unneccesary variables)

```
c2 = reshape(cumsum(reshape(randi([0 255],[500 500]),1,[])),[500 500]);
```